# Cannot Position Correctly with HTML

Tags: html, css, positioning, absolute, marquee

Basically I want the image to fall down the screen all the way through the right side of the window and I tried it like this (see snippet below)

```css
#falling2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<marquee id="falling2" height="100%" direction=down scrollamount="20">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
</marquee>
```

However, it stays glued to the left side for some reason.

I tried solutions from here on stack overflow but they did not seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#falling2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -2;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<marquee id="falling2" height="100%" direction=down scrollamount="20">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <style type="text/css">
    #falling2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0; 
    z-index: -2; 
    text-align:  right;
}
</style>
```

set text-align:right

Answer (score 1):

There is a css property known as text align , which is used to align inner elements (with respect to outer element border/boundary), have a look at it in below snippet

```css
#falling2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        text-align:right;
        z-index: -2;
    }
```

```html
<marquee id="falling2" height="100%" direction=down scrollamount="20">
        <img src="image.png">
    </marquee>
```